# Can't connect to mongodb from outside even when specify bind_ip=0.0.0.0

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am using mongodb docker service. I start mongodb by

```
docker run --rm -p 28019:27017 -e bind_ip=0.0.0.0 --user mongodb mongo
```

> because there is another mongodb running, so I use port 28019.

When I tried to connect this mongodb docker by MongoDB Compass, it says `connect ECONNREFUSED 183.62.225.108:28019`.

This is the mongodb docker log(all):

```
2019-09-19T06:33:07.630+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-09-19T06:33:07.634+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=c45e02bda30b
2019-09-19T06:33:07.634+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.11
2019-09-19T06:33:07.634+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 417d1a712e9f040d54beca8e4943edce218e9a8c
2019-09-19T06:33:07.634+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-09-19T06:33:07.634+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-09-19T06:33:07.634+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-09-19T06:33:07.635+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-09-19T06:33:07.635+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2019-09-19T06:33:07.635+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-09-19T06:33:07.635+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-09-19T06:33:07.635+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } }
2019-09-19T06:33:07.636+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=9882M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-09-19T06:33:08.209+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1568874788:209440][1:0x7f8c3ed47a80], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-09-19T06:33:08.215+0000 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2019-09-19T06:33:08.226+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-09-19T06:33:08.227+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 5224c436-3a0f-46b5-a368-6463fce5ad52
2019-09-19T06:33:08.238+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0
2019-09-19T06:33:08.247+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 2965f894-387e-4aa1-bf05-1b18d9a05566
2019-09-19T06:33:08.260+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2019-09-19T06:33:08.261+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2019-09-19T06:33:08.262+0000 I STORAGE  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] createCollection: config.system.sessions with generated UUID: 4acb36dc-4626-43a3-a2cf-007004bae39a
2019-09-19T06:33:08.299+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index on: config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 }
2019-09-19T06:33:08.299+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh]     building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-09-19T06:33:08.332+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
```

This is my Compass error:(I am sure the host address is right)
[image]

### What I have tried

I have checked the port `28019`, it's off. So I turn it on by

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=28019/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

But I still can't connect to my server.

### Others

System:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
```

Docker version:

`Docker version 1.13.1, build 87f2fab/1.13.1`

Mongodb image:

```
docker.io/mongo    latest    f7adfc4dbcf5  7 weeks ago         413 MB
```

## Update:

I have turned off SELinux, this problem is still there.

This centos system is created by vmware.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try by disabling SELinux on your system.

Check SELinux Status,

```
$ sestatus
```

You can temporarily change the SELinux mode from targeted to permissive with the following command:

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

However, this change will be valid for the current runtime session only.

To permanently disable SELinux on your CentOS 7 system, follow the steps below:

```
1. Open the /etc/selinux/config file and set the SELINUX mod to disabled
2. Save the file and reboot your CentOS system with:
    $ sudo shutdown -r now
3. Once the system boots up, verify the change with the sestatus command
    The output should look like this:

    $ SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried `sudo setenforce 0` and the `Current mode` is `permissive` now. But I still can't connect to that host.

Comment: I turned off SELinux and reboot, now the status of SELinux is disabled. But mongodb still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please post the output of below commands,

1. docker port your_container_name 27017/tcp
2. docker ps -a

Comment: I have add the output image to my discription. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I see the broken image icon

Comment: Thank you, now I can see the image.

Comment: Thank you bro, I give up. This problem has taken me so much time so I decided to leave it there and buy a server.